# Cosa vuol dire "accartocciata" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Cosimo fiutò il pericolo, o forse non fiutò niente: si sentì deriso per lo spadino e volle sfoderarlo per punto d'onore. Lo brandì alto, la lama sfiorò il sacco, lui lo vide, e con un'**accartocciata** lo strappò di mano ai due ladroncelli e lo fece volar via.

La mia domanda è: cos'è questa "accartocciata" che appare in questo passaggio? Non ho trovato questo termine in nessun dizionario. Ho visto però che c'era "accartocciare", ma le definizioni di questo verbo non sembrano avere niente a che vedere con il contesto di questo brano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sembra gergo della scherma, anche se antiquato:

> [**cartòccio**](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/cartoccio/) s. m. [der. di *carta*]. – […] **6.** Nella scherma, uscita in tempo (detta anche *passata sotto*) ormai in disuso, ma largamente impiegata nei secoli scorsi.

Considererei *cartoccio*, *cartocciata* e *accartocciata* come sinonimi in questo contesto.

Comment: E il significato di "uscita in tempo" sarebbe [questo](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/uscita-in-tempo).

Comment: E l'uso di un termine antiquato dovrebbe essere dovuto al fatto che la storia raccontata da Calvino si svolge nel XVIII secolo.